# How do I switch to human-readable crash dump timestamps?

Tags: debian, crash

My system crashed and I need to know the time of the crash **before rebooting**. I can easily determine it by adding the (last) timestamp in the crash dump to the boot time, but I forgot the boot time (I don't remember the exact second). To make things worse, I didn't post a Facebook message that I booted up. So rebooting is my only first step.

Next time this happens, I prefer the system to use the absolute time in the crash dump.

Comment: `last|grep boot` might be used to find when it was booted.

Comment: @JuliePelletier For that I'd need to be able to press Enter.

Comment: Can you mount the disk containing the /var/log directory on another system? Then you can run `last -f /path/to/wtmp reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

If your system does not log remotely, you're pretty much out of luck (unless you can access its disks without rebooting). But your **before rebooting** requirement seems artificial, what's the point of it? Maybe we could find a way around if you explained your problem in more depth.

Comment: If I wait for 3 more h, the system may unfreeze by itself or may stay crashed. Waiting for more than 3h never made a difference. Now I just came back to my computer and I really need to use it but it's even more important to wait and recover my session. Still, it's more important to continue my work than to wait for 3h only to confirm that there's no way to recover my session.

Comment: Then configure remote logging, or add a startup task which posts to Facebook.